# How to count reapeted lists/dictionaries into a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counting

i'm recently learning python, and my question is: How to count repeated lists which is contained by a list.

For example: list1 = [[sublist1],[sublist2], [sublist3]] and so on.

I understand by elements it's required to use the fuction count(), but I don't know how to execute my program neither to lists into lists nor dict into lists.

Thank you guys!

I'm really lost. I've searched a lot, but without success.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by how to count. `len(list1)` will tell you how many sublists you have. Is that what you want? Or are you looking for something like `list1.count([1, 2])`. Or maybe individual elements: `sum(l.count(1) for l in list1)`?  An example with expected results would really make this cleared.

Comment: Please clarify what you wanna obtain

Comment: @Mark sorry for not being clear at all, sorry, i'm a beginner. I mean something like list1.count([1, 2]), does it exist?  I'm working on a project which I must count some combinations of elements, for instance, price = [[car, 20000, 'tv', '1000, 'sofa', '600'], [car, 10000, 'tv', 800, 'sofa', 500], [car, 20000, 'tv', '1000, 'sofa', '600']...]. Imagine I want to count all combinations of lists.

Comment: `list1.count([1, 2])` will count the occurrence of `[1, 2]` in `list1`. Have you tried it?